# relation between photon number and energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, photons

Suppose there are two light beams. One is red while the other is violet. The energy of both is the same.

Which one of these beams has a larger number of photons, or is the number of photons relevant?

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Do you mean "intensity" or "power" instead of "energy"?

Answer (score 3):

The energy of a single photon is $E_\gamma = h \cdot \nu$ or $E_\gamma = h \cdot \frac{c}{\lambda}$, where $h$ is Plank's Constant, $\nu$ is the frequency, $c$ is the speed of light, and $\lambda$ is the wavelength.

Logically, the total number of particles is $N = E_\Sigma/E_\gamma$, where $E_\Sigma$ is the total energy of the beam. Thus a higher energy per particle means a lower number of particles.

Comment: I think you mean more in the first line instead of less, especially since you state it correctly in the last sentence.

Comment: @GeorgeG In the last sentence, I state, "thus a higher energy per particle means a lower number of particles." Conversely, a lower energy per particle means a higher number of particles. Red photons are lower energy than violet photons, thus a red beam has more photons than a violet beam of the same total energy.

Comment: You made a typo. I didn't edit because I thought it was below the length threshhold, but @Gigi Butbaia fixed it.